# $scope members not updating after function call with $http

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, asynchronous

I'm working on revamping another project with some AngularJS. I am having a problem where my `$scope.script` and `$scope.workInstruction` variables are not being updated after calling my `$scope.dbQuery` function that contains a `$http.post()` directive.

The `$http.post()` call is successful, but the returned data is not being reflected in my `$scope`

I am expecting that once the `$http.post()` call finishes, the script and workInstruction should then also be updated from 2-way data-binding.

When I call the `$http.post()` method directly and then assign the `$scope.script` and `$scope.workInstruction` values at the end, they are updated automatically because of the `.$apply()` wrapper.

- *How can I emulate the same response but calling the function with my
  current setup?*

I tried using `$scope.$apply()`, but had no luck! Perhaps I was using it incorrectly? I am new to angular, so any advice on how to get these values to update in the view would be appreciated :)

**Here is the HTML snippet:**

```
<div class="container" ng-controller="results">
        <button ng-click="sendPost()"/>Query!</button>
        <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon" id="script-addon" style="width: 100px">Script:</span>
            <textarea class="form-control" name="script" aria-describedby="script-addon">{{ script }}</textarea>
        </div> 

        <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon" id="work-addon" style="width: 100px">Work Instruction:</span>
            <textarea class="form-control" name="script" aria-describedby="work-addon">{{ workInstruction }}</textarea>
        </div> 
</div>
```

**Here is the AngularJS:**

```
myApp.controller('results', ['$scope', '$http', '$log', function ($scope, $http, $log) {
$scope.url = "php/dbquery.php";
$scope.tool = 'EAMS';
$scope.category = 'Admin';
$scope.sub_category = 'Access';
$scope.issue = 'Account Locked';

$scope.sendPost = function () {

    var data = $.param({
        table: $scope.tool,
        tool : $scope.tool,
        category: $scope.category,
        sub_category: $scope.sub_category,
        issue: $scope.issue
    });

    var config = {
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8;'
        }
    };
    /* THIS IS PROBLEM LOCATION; $scope.script returns undefined */
    $scope.script = $scope.dbQuery($scope.url, data, config);
    $log.info("Script: " + $scope.script);

    var data = $.param({
        table: $scope.tool,
        tool : $scope.tool,
        category: $scope.category,
        sub_category: $scope.sub_category,
        issue: $scope.issue,
        flag: true
    });

    /* THIS IS PROBLEM LOCATION; $scope.workInstruction returns undefined */
    $scope.workInstruction = $scope.dbQuery($scope.url, data, config);        
    $log.info('Work Instruction: ' + $scope.workInstruction);
  }; // End sendPost()

$scope.dbQuery = function dbQuery(url, data, config) {
    $log.debug("In dbuery");
    $http.post(url, data, config)
        .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            var result = data[0];
            $log.debug('res: ' + result);
            return result;
        })
        .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            var result = 'Bad query: ' + data +
                "<hr />status: "  + status +
                "<hr />headers: " + header +
                "<hr />config: "  + config;
            return result;
        });
    }
}]); // End controller
```

**Here is console output:**

```
    In dbuery
angular.min.js:107 Script: undefined
angular.min.js:107 In dbuery
angular.min.js:107 Work Instruction: undefined
angular.min.js:107 res: Status: Resolved (No Further Action Required)

User,

Your EAMS account has been reactivated. Please reset your password by using the Forgot Password on the login page.

Please see the Ericsson Password Policy below:

    1) Passwords for individual user accounts shall consist of a minimum of 8 characters, being a combination of at least 3 of the following 4 character types; lowercase, uppercase, numeral and special characters.

    2) Change of passwords shall be enforced every 90 days.

    3) Prevent passwords which are equal to the user ID, ericsson, and Ericsson

    4) Prevent password re-use of 15 generations and allow not more than 3 password changes per day.

    5) Accounts shall be locked after 6 consecutive failed attempts to log in within 30 minutes. Automatic unlock is allowed after 30 minutes.

This ticket is considered closed.

Thank you,
angular.min.js:107 res: Verify account has company email address, company assigned, role(s) assigned & Clear Expire. 

If no roles or company, DO NOT Clear Expire. The account will not work for user. 

Do not unlock if public email address. Send Company email mandatory QP.

If Supplier, and you cannot tell from email address, ask user. 

If Ericsson, try to Lync for additional info. If not available, ask user via email.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To keep myself from having to create an `$http.post()` for every single query `$scope` member that I needed to retrieve from my database, I passed a parameter that contained what I was trying to query, to my `$scope.dbQuery` method. This allowed my callbacks to dynamically update my view and models appropriately.

```
    $scope.dbQuery = function dbQuery(url, data, config, member) {
    $log.debug(member);

    $http.post(url, data, config)
        .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {            

            switch (member) {
                case 'tool':
                    $scope.toolSel = data;
                    break;

                case 'category':
                    break;

                case 'subCategory':
                    break;

                case 'issue':
                    break;

                case 'script':
                    $scope.script = data[0];
                    break;

                case 'workInstruction':
                    $scope.workInstruction = data[0];
                    break;

                default:
                    break;
            }
        })
        .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            var result = 'Bad query: ' + data +
                "<hr />status: "  + status +
                "<hr />headers: " + header +
                "<hr />config: "  + config;
            $log.error(result);
        });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

$scope.dbQuery returns immediately, the 'returns' from success/error are asynchrous call via promise api. you should assign the $scope.script directly within the success callback handler

Comment: I want to be able to use that function whether I want to update the script, workInstruction, etc. without having to write an entirely new call for each $scope member.  If I do what you suggest, each member would require its own call. Is there a way to dynamically assign my scope members?